# swiftUI contextMenu has unwanted blurred background

Tags: ios, swift, view, swiftui, contextmenu

I had a the following code using SwiftUI contextMenu.

```
ForEach(...) { ... in
     NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()) {
          HStack {
               Image(...) 
               Text(...)
          }
     }
     .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: { Button(...) }
```

The expected behaviour is image below.
[image]

But at 80% of the time, the contextMenu has an UNWANTED blurred background like below. As it has been applied a weird blurred effect on top of it.

[image]

Anyone knows what caused the issue?

Comment: It might be because you're adding it on top of a NavigationLink, which has a "highlighted" look when it's pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The blur is because your button is highlighted. I'm facing a similar issue.

By the way, simply add this before `.contextMenu { }` to make it rounded

```
.contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: ...))
```